# Generate a sorted key for a sorted value

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I need to maintain a mapping from a key to a string value, and also a mapping from the value back to the key. I need to make sure that both of these lists are sorted at all times. New values can be added to the list at any time. What is the best data structure(s) to use so that when a new value is added, we can maintain the two sorted lists without having to regenerate many keys and without ending up with an unbalanced tree?

Comment: Two hash maps which contain references to a sorted array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be described as "In this problem, out goal is to maintain a linked list with an explicit label for
each node such that the labels are monotonic throughout the list, subject to inserting and deleting
at any given location."?

This is section 3 of http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.897/spring05/lec/lec24.pdf. They show how you can maintain a table of keys in sorted order, with gaps, by viewing it as an implicit tree structure, in which reorganizing the keys within a section of table is equivalent to re-balancing a subtree.